# How can I make grep stop after hitting a first pattern match in a large file?

Tags: shell, grep

I have a large number of rows like this:

```
a|b|c
e|f|2
h|i|j
```

I want to find the FIRST row with numbers ONLY in the 3rd column (that would be the 2nd one in the example). How can I grep that without dumping all data and pipe it into head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-m1` option in grep:

```
grep -m1 "[0-9]$" file
```

As per `man grep`:

```
 -m num, --max-count=num
         Stop reading the file after num matches.
```

Or more accurately do it using awk:

```
awk -F'|' '$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/{print; exit}' file
e|f|2
```

Comment: Note that `-m` is a GNUism.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX solution is to use `sed` and exit after the first match:

```
sed -n '/|[0-9]*$/{p;q;}' file    # print and quit
```